# sys.columns shows details but table missing from sys.tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I was wanting to know in which table in the database a certain column exists. So I used the sys.columns with a where condition, and this gave me some object_id.

```
select * from sys.columns where name like 'mycol%'
```

Next I went about finding the actual name of this table from the object_id received from the above query, as follows from sys.tables. But my select statement returns an empty result. Does this mean such a table does not exist in the database. If so, how is sys.columns telling me that the column I'm looking for lies in a table with this object_id?

```
select * from sys.tables where object_id='584895884'
```

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2014.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that it is not a table, but either a View, or a Table-Valued Function, or one of several other types of objects. Use this instead:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM sys.objects
WHERE [object_id] = 584895884;
```

Please note that the `[object_id]` field is a number, not a string, so shouldn't be quoted.

You can also do this in a single query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   sys.columns sc
INNER JOIN sys.objects so
        ON so.[object_id] = sc.[object_id]
WHERE sc.name LIKE N'mycol%';
```

The `type` and `type_desc` fields from `sys.objects` will indicate what type of object the column is found in. The possibilities I see in one of my databases are:

> type_desc (type)
>
> ---
>
> CLR_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION (FT)
>   INTERNAL_TABLE (IT)
>   SQL_INLINE_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION (IF)
>   SQL_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION (TF)
>   SYSTEM_TABLE (S)
>   TYPE_TABLE (TT)
>   USER_TABLE (U)
>   VIEW (V)

The `sys.tables` system view will only contain objects of type `U` / `USER_TABLE`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. Is sys.tables like a subset of sys.objects containing only U / USER_TABLE? . I see that sys.objects contains many types like you have listed above.

Comment: @IAMTubby Yes, there are many object-type-specific system views, such as `sys.views`, `sys.sql_modules` (for Procedures, Functions, Views, and probably Triggers), etc. But these are more than just filtered  Views of `sys.objects`; many/most of them contain additional or different fields specific to that object type. Look through the results of `SELECT * FROM sys.system_views;` for all of the options.